# Cauchy sequence such that don't have limes in C[0,1]

Tags: sequences-and-series, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Give an example of series $f_n \in C[0,1]$ such that $f_n$ is Cauchy sequence in norm $$\|(a_n)\|_p = \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|^p \right)^{1/p}$$ and $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$$ don't exsists in $C[0,1]$.

For me the very big problem is to find Cauchy sequence in this norm. Of course, I know definition of Cauchy sequence. Could you give me an example of series which should I consider?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use the $L_p$-norm? ($\Vert f\Vert=\bigl(\int_0^1 |f|^p\bigr)^{1/p}$.) Also, you have "series" written when I think you mean "sequence".

Comment: I suppose you may be right. But the question is still open.

Comment: If they don't have limes, how will they make mojitos??? :-(

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find examples in nearly every text books. The standard example is some kind of ramp function, for instance this continuous approximation of $sign(x-\tfrac12)$
$$
f_ε(x)=\begin{cases}
-1& 0\le x<\tfrac12-ε\\
\tfrac1ε(x-\tfrac12)&\tfrac12-ε\le x\le \tfrac12+ε\\
1&\tfrac12+ε<x\le 1
\end{cases}
$$